# Testimonial section with HTML tags

Tags: html, css

I created this testimonial on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/JGallardo/pen/zGyid)

[image: current quote]

I am a bit skeptical about a few things in my HTML structure. For example, I typically see testimonials enclosed in `<div>`s with custom classes. In my case I used a `<blockquote>` but had to overwrite a lot of rules.

Also wondering if enclosing the author in `<strong>` tags was wise.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <blockquote>
    &ldquo;Such cool. Much awesome. WOW&rdquo;
  </blockquote>
  <p class="author">
    &ndash; 
    <strong>Doge</strong>, 
    <a href="#">The Moon</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* == resets == */
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
/* == project == */
body { 
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(240, 240, 240);
  color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 24px auto;
}

blockquote {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 17px;
}
p.author {
  background-color: transparent;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height:22px;
  margin: 24px 0 0 18px;
}
strong {
  color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
}

a {
  color: rgb(64, 131, 169);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- I would say that for it to be semantically accurate, the `author` should be a part of the `blockquote`, perhaps using a `footer`.
- You should include a `cite` attribute if the quote has a source.
- The quote content should be inside a paragraph element.
- I guess now you don't need the wrapper any more.

  ```
    <blockquote cite="http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/doge">
      <p>&ldquo;Such cool. Much awesome. WOW&rdquo;</p>

       <footer class="author">
         &ndash; 
         <strong>Doge</strong>, 
         <a href="#">The Moon</a>
       </footer>
     </blockquote>
  ```
- To make it look the same I had to change these bits of CSS:

  ```
  blockquote {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0;
  }

  blockquote p {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding: 17px;
  }

  footer.author {
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height:22px;
    margin: 24px 0 0 18px;
  }
  ```
- [Here's the result](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ufsxA).

Comment: Such CSS. Much helpful. Wow

Comment: It was pointed out by Unor that citation should be placed outside the `<blockquote>`. [the blockquote element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element)

Comment: @JGallardo That's not what it says... The `cite` attribute is **on** the `<blockquote>` element.

Comment: @JGallardo Sorry, you meant the author. I didn't read the other answer.

Answer (score 12):

1. Your use of blockquote is correct. You can pretty much use div's for anything you want, but blockquote is the preferred way for quoting other people or sources. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_blockquote.asp
2. Your use of strong is incorrect in my opinion.

From http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strong.asp

> In HTML 4.01, the  tag defines strong emphasized text, but in
>   HTML5 it defines important text.

I don't think the person's name is important to your website.

Your other option of course would be to use something like

```
<span class="quotersname">Doge</span>

.quotersname { font-size: 18px; font-weight: 800; }
```

However, I don't think it's that big of a deal either way. But I would personally use something like the second way.

Answer (score 5):

Using `blockquote` would be appropriate.

<s>Jivings [suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/41022/16414) to include the author in the `blockquote`, but please note that this is [not allowed in HTML5 (CR)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element):</s>

> Attribution for the quotation, if any, must be placed outside the `blockquote` element.

**UPDATE:** The [new HTML5 CR](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) changed this rule:

> […] optionally with a citation which must be within a `footer` or `cite` element […]

([`cite`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140204/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element) was also changed, so that it can be used for person names now.)

So these are allowed now:

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>Such cool. Much awesome. WOW.</p>
  <footer class="author">Doge</footer>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p>Such cool. Much awesome. WOW.</p>
  <cite class="author">Doge</cite>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p>Such cool. Much awesome. WOW.</p>
  <footer>
    <cite class="author">Doge</cite>
  </footer>
</blockquote>
```

---

Using `strong` is not appropriate in all cases, but there might be cases where it could be used. Remember that it represents "[strong importance](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element)".

In some other cases, the [`b` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element) could be used.

If you need an element for the person’s name suitable for all contexts/situations, you’d have to go with [`span`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element).

---

Depending in which context the testimonial is published, you might consider to use the [`figure` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element).

If you use `figure` (or a sectioning element like `article`) for a testimonial, you should enclose the author in a [`footer` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#the-footer-element). (See the [last example in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21489636/1591669) to a different question.)

Comment: Nice! I hadn't read that section. Thanks!

Comment: @Jivings, does that change your answer?

Comment: @JGallardo Yes, you should abide by the HTML5 spec.