# Cardshifter website meta-tags for SEO

Tags: html, html5

I have written the following meta-tags for SEO, please let me know if you think this could use any improvement. I have used [this article](http://www.iacquire.com/blog/18-meta-tags-every-webpage-should-have-in-2013) to help me put it together. I have left out the page content on purpose, if you wish to see it I posted it [here on CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69686/website-template-for-cardshifter-game) and [on Github](https://github.com/Cardshifter/cardshifter.github.io/blob/master/page-template.html) (note the following updates have not been committed yet, they are only in my local directory).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="" lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"> <!-- Schema.org is for Google+ meta-data - See other meta-tags within head section) -->
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/favicon.ico" />

    <!-- META-TAGS -->

      <!-- Standard meta-tags -->
      <title>Cardshifter TCG</title>
      <meta name="description" content="Try Cardshifter trading card game (TCG), an open source multiplayer game!" />
      <meta name="author" content="https://github.com/Cardshifter" />
      <link rel="author" href="https://github.com/Cardshifter" />
      <link rel="publisher" href="https://github.com/Cardshifter" />

      <!-- Google+ Schema.org tags -->
      <meta itemprop="name" content="Cardshifter Trading Care Game">
      <meta itemprop="description" content="Try Cardshifter trading card game (TCG), an open source multiplayer game!">
      <meta itemprop="image" content="/images/cardshifter-logo.png">

      <!-- Facebook OpenGraph tags -->
      <meta property="og:title" content="Cardshifter Trading Care Game" />
      <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
      <meta property="og:image" content="/images/cardshifter-logo.png" />
      <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.CardShifter.com/" />
      <meta property="og:description" content="Try Cardshifter trading card game (TCG), an open source multiplayer game!" />
      <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID" />  <!-- NEED TO MAKE USER ID FOR CARDSHIFTER -->

      <!-- Twitter tags -->
      <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary" />
      <meta property="twitter:url" content="https://twitter.com/Cardshifter" />
      <meta property="twitter:title" content="Cardshifter Trading Care Game" />
      <meta property="twitter:description" content="Try Cardshifter trading card game (TCG), an open source multiplayer game!" />
      <meta property="twitter:image" content ="/images/cardshifter-logo.png" />

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="cardshifter.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- page content removed -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Cardshifter Trading Care Game` sounds sweet

Comment: @jacwah ... Yeah, I'll fix that too lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `author` name is not for URLs

You use

```
<meta name="author" content="https://github.com/Cardshifter" />
```

but the [`author` name](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/document-metadata.html#meta-author) expects a name, not a URL (bold emphasis mine):

> The value must be **a free-form string giving the name** of one of the page's authors.

#### `link` instead of `meta` if URL

If the value is a URL, you [must use the `link` element instead of `meta`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24659620/1591669).

So for the following elements, you should use `link` instead of `meta` (and `href` instead of `content`):

```
<meta itemprop="image" content="/images/cardshifter-logo.png">
<meta property="og:image" content="/images/cardshifter-logo.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.CardShifter.com/" />
<meta property="twitter:url" content="https://twitter.com/Cardshifter" />
<meta property="twitter:image" content ="/images/cardshifter-logo.png" />
```

#### End slash

Sometimes you have an end slash, sometimes not (as can be seen in the `meta` elements above). Not wrong, but why not stick to one variant?

#### RDFa instead of Microdata

You are using RDFa for the OpenGraph (and perhaps Twitter) metadata, and Microdata for Schema.org. Why not stick to one syntax? You could use RDFa also for Schema.org.

#### `twitter:` prefix is not defined

You are using the prefix `twitter` in your RDFa for the Twitter tags, but this prefix is not defined in the [RDFa Core Initial Context](http://www.w3.org/2011/rdfa-context/rdfa-1.1), so you’d have to define it explicitly.

I don’t know if Twitter defines a vocabulary for this at all, so maybe you’d have to use plain HTML5 `meta`/`link` elements instead of RDFa. The corresponding names are defined in https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions#Registered_Extensions, so you can use them in HTML5’s `name` attribute of the `meta` element. As so often, they got it wrong with `meta` vs. `link`, and as the link types are not defined in http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions, you might have to use `meta` even for `link`.

Comment: You seem to know a lot about SEO... Thanks for both of your answers!

Comment: I was reading about Microdata, do you know what criteria I should use to select one or the other? (that or RDFa)

Comment: @Phrancis: I’ve written about some of the [differences between Microdata and RDFa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25888436/1591669), and my advice for choosing a syntax is in the "What to do?" section.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using both? In the end, what I'm trying to do is just reach the widest possible audience...

Comment: @Phrancis: The widest possible audience? Then use both. There always might be a consumer that only supports one syntax. -- But personally, I would only do this if it doesn’t cost much effort. Having one syntax should be enough for most use cases.

Answer (score 5):

### 1. Charset

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
> ```

You declare a HTML5 doctype and two charsets. You can remove the first of the two rules and leave this:

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
```

### 2. IE rendering engine

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
> ```

The browser should choose the fitting rendering engine on its own. Setting `IE=edge` should do nothing in most cases unless the default rendering engine was changed by the user.

That said, it doesn’t do harm.

### 3. Comments

> ```
> <!-- META-TAGS -->
> ```

Don’t state the obvious. We can see every `<meta>` thing is a meta tag. Also there are other things under this comment as well. `title` and `link` are not meta tags.

I’d also leave out comments like the ones for `twitter tags`. Separating them by new lines creates enough distinctiveness.

### 4. HTML Shiv/Shim

> ```
> <!--[if lt IE 9]>
>   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
>   <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
> <![endif]-->
> ```

Don’t omit the `type` attribute for browsers that don’t understand HTML5, because it is not valid HTML 4/XHTML. You include the shiv to ensure IE8 support for HTML5 elements, so you should definitely have it there.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

### 4. SEO

Having a good structured document is the one thing which helps. You have description that search engines use, you have a page title, you probably will have fitting headings in your actual content.

However that’s just the foundation. With just that, search engines won’t give you a good ranking. The important part is the content. Make sure you have a good [document outline](http://html5doctor.com/outlines/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the document outline link, I will certainly check it out, as well as put in your improvements!